# Unable to check the check boxes using single click

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to uncheck all the check boxes on click of a radio button, but when I am trying to check the check boxes again I have to do a double click instead of a single click selection

```
if(($('#radAllBaxDocs').is(':checked')) || ($('#radLabels').is(':checked')){
    $('.sol-checkbox').each(function(){this.checked = false;});
}
```

Comment: can you add your html part too, so that we can help you  Or an example link will more better

Comment: Have you check your console for errors? Seems like you are missing the closing `)` for the if statement. Also, would be helpful if you add a minimal working example that puts in evidence the problem you have by also adding the `HTML`.

Comment: since it is a client code cannot provide the link,

Comment: HTML is as below, where value are getting populated dynamically


<div class="col-md-12 clear"></div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-2"><input onclick="clearDocuments();" id="radStudy"  name="SiteType" type="radio"/> <label> Study:</label></div>
<div class="col-md-4" id="divStudy">

Comment: if(($('#radAllBaxDocs').is(':checked')) || ($('#radLabels').is(':checked')))
{
$("#divStudy").children().children().children().children().children().children($(".sol-checkbox")).prop("checked",false);

$('input:radio[name=character]')[0].checked = true;

$("#divStudy").children().children().children("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("#divDocuments").children().children().children("input").prop('disabled', true);
}

Comment: @paruupreti You should edit your question and include your html code, because you cannot format code in comments, it'll be better for us to read it and help you!

Comment: You should consider editing your question rather and putting the HTML in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please You can try the .prop to uncheck the Checkbox... as Below Code

```js
$('#radAllBaxDocs, #radLabels').change(function(){
  if($('#radAllBaxDocs, #radLabels').is(':checked'))
  {
    $('.sol-checkbox').prop("checked",false);
  }
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="radAllBaxDocs" name="1" > Hello
<input type="radio" id="radLabels" name="1"> Hello

<input type="checkbox" value="Hello" class="sol-checkbox">1
<input type="checkbox" value="Hello" class="sol-checkbox">2
<input type="checkbox" value="Hello" class="sol-checkbox">3
<input type="checkbox" value="Hello" class="sol-checkbox">4
<input type="checkbox" value="Hello" class="sol-checkbox">5
```

Comment: tried this, it unchecks the values, but the problem still persists, this problem happens when i click on other radio button and then again select options in this dropdown, for first time it works fine.

Comment: <div class="col-md-12 clear"></div> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="col-md-2"><input onclick="clearDocuments();" id="radStudy" name="SiteType" type="radio"/> <label> Study:</label></div> <div class="col-md-4" id="divStudy">

if(($('#radAllBaxDocs').is(':checked')) || ($('#radLabels').is(':checked'))) { $("#divStudy").children().children().children().children().c‌​hildren().children($‌​(".sol-checkbox")).p‌​rop("checked",false)‌​; $('input:radio[name=character]')[0].checked = true; $("#divStudy").children().children().children("input").prop(‌​'disabled', true);